# Connect HTC Nexus one to a PC

Tags: android, sdk, driver, nexus-one

Using the command prompt i want to check if my HTC nexus one is connected to the pc using the "adb devices" command.

I have installed all the available packages for the Android SDK including Usb Driver package, revision 4 and i have the USB debbuging enabled.

I would like to change it to Usb Driver package Revision 3 since i have Nexus one.
On the available packages i can find only the revision 4. How can i change it back to 3 and maybe this will fix the problem?

Can you please help me to find out what the problem is and how to solve it, so by using "adb devices" command i can be able to see my HTC Nexus one.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it not work now? I assume the newest packages should include all the previous ones. What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Today i upgraded it to revision 4 and it cannot see the device. It's show me the emulator device but not nexus one.. I think that the problem might be the upgrade because the suitable one for HTC nexus is revision 3.

Comment: Do you have USB debugging enabled?  Without it, the computer WILL NOT see your phone(not as a phone, maybe as a storage device).  BTW, responses to someone should start with @[NAME] where [NAME] is the persons name(obviously).  That way the system will notify people when you respond to them.

Comment: @John Thank you for your advice. Yes my USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

Go to My Computer> Open Control Panel> Device Manager> Disk Drives

Then right click on "Google, Inc.Nexus One USB Device"

Update Driver Software

Choose the option “Browse my computer for driver software”

Put the path (C:\Program Files\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\google-usb_driver)

Click next.

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Read this page and follow the steps

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

In archlinux I have:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8",ATTR{idProduct}=="681c",SYMLINK+="android_adb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8",ATTR{idProduct}=="681c",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"
```